# History handling scenario issue

Tags: teradata

I need help with the query to handle below scenarios.

The below record is active:

```
ID          start_dt        status  end_dt
-------------------------------------------------
18,593,122  1/15/07 14:38   A       12/11/07 8:45
18,593,122  12/11/07 8:45   C       12/11/07 8:45
18,593,122  12/11/07 8:45   A       11/13/11 0:00
18,593,122  11/13/11 0:00   C       12/26/11 10:36
18,593,122  12/26/11 10:36  A       ?
```

Below is closed:

```
ID          start_dt        status  end_dt
-------------------------------------------------
18,593,122  1/15/07 14:38   A       12/11/07 8:45
18,593,122  12/11/07 8:45   C       ?
```

I have to insert records in the table where the records are not correctly ended.
For ex there are records like below:

```
ID          start_dt        status  end_dt
-------------------------------------------------
18,593,122  1/15/07 14:38   A       12/11/07 8:45
```

In the above record the Closed record is missing.

I have to identify such records and insert in the table.

Below sample getting impacted.

```
10,866  7/29/96 0:01    A       12/27/03 14:16
10,866  7/25/00 0:01    A       8/20/00 23:59
10,866  8/20/00 23:59   C       10/2/02 13:00
10,866  10/2/02 13:00   A       7/25/04 14:11
10,866  12/27/03 14:16  C       7/25/04 14:11
10,866  7/25/04 14:11   C       7/25/04 14:11
10,866  7/25/04 14:11   A       ?
10,866  5/28/11 16:24   T       5/28/11 16:24
```

**Below scenario not able to handle:**
Records with accs_meth_status_type_cd=’A’ and end date not null(Highlighted below).
Expected: Record with accs_meth_status_type_cd=’C’ should be inserted
Actual: Record with accs_meth_status_type_cd=’C’ is not getting inserted

```
10,866  7/29/96 0:01    A       12/27/03 14:16
10,866  7/25/00 0:01    A       8/20/00 23:59
10,866  8/20/00 23:59   C       10/2/02 13:00
10,866  10/2/02 13:00   A       7/25/04 14:11
10,866  12/15/04 14:16  A       ?
```

Comment: Closed and open records seems same. Is there any difference? both has `end_dt = NULL` for latest record?

Comment: Active records have end date as null and there will be no record with status c  and closed records have A record with end date not null plus another record with status c and end date as null

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, a correctly closed record (i.e. ID) consists of:

- Row #1: Status <> 'C' and End_Dt IS NOT NULL
- Row #2: Status = 'C' and End_Dt IS NULL
- End_Dt in Row #1 = Start_Dt in Row #2

Assuming that's correct, you can do something like this to find records that should be closed (i.e. have Row #1, but are missing Row #2):

```
INSERT INTO mytbl (ID, Start_Dt, Status, End_Dt)
SELECT 
    a.ID, 
    a.End_Dt, -- Use the unclosed row's End_Dt as the Start_Dt for the new "to-be-inserted" row
    'C', 
    NULL
FROM mytbl a
WHERE a.status <> 'C' 
AND a.End_Dt IS NOT NULL -- Get rows that should be considered closed
AND (a.ID, a.End_Dt) NOT IN (
    -- Check for corresponding records that do not also have a 'C' row
    -- You can also do this as a LEFT JOIN above
    SELECT ID, Start_Dt 
    FROM mytbl 
    WHERE Status = 'C' -- Check for presence of 'C' rows
    AND End_Dt IS NULL -- Check
)
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY End_Dt DESC) = 1 -- Only return one row per "unclosed" record
;
```

This won't handle all the edge cases, but it should get you started.  Let me know if that's what you're looking for.

**Updated**
I ran the query above against the 5 new rows you provided, and this the result I got:

```
    id      start_dt                    status  end_dt
1   10,866  7/25/2000 00:01:00.000000   A       8/20/2000 23:59:00.000000
2   10,866  8/20/2000 23:59:00.000000   C       10/2/2002 13:00:00.000000
3   10,866  7/29/1996 00:01:00.000000   A       12/27/2003 14:16:00.000000
4   10,866  10/2/2002 13:00:00.000000   A       7/25/2004 14:11:00.000000
5   10,866  12/27/2003 14:16:00.000000  A       ?
6   10,866  7/25/2004 14:11:00.000000   C       ?
```

Rows #1-5 are the original rows.  Row #6 is the newly inserted 'C' row, which corresponds to row #4, the old improperly closed 'A' row.  Is this what you are expecting or no?

Comment: Thanks Ravioli..Will get back to you. :)

Comment: Dear @Ravioli,
With the current code, records with temporarily Terminated are also getting closed and another record is getting inserted with C .
Attached the sample in the above code.
Please advise.

Comment: If you only want to close 'A' rows that are missing the corresponding 'C' row, then change the WHERE clause to be:  

`WHERE a.status = 'A'`

The query expects the 'C' row to have a `Start_Dt` value = to the `End_Dt` value of the 'A' row.  If the "_Dt" values don't match, it will be considered unclosed and a new 'C' row will be inserted.  Also, this query won't handle cases with multiple unclosed 'A' rows for a given record.  It will only look at the most recent one.  It will take more logic to correctly insert 'C' rows in the middle of the row sequence.

Comment: Can you please modify the latest sample results you posted above to show the "before" row set and the "after" row set.  This will help to see what the original state was and what rows were added.

Comment: Thanks Ravioli for your time.Yes, i want to close 'A' rows that are missing the corresponding 'C' row.
where can i add that condition in the not in part??
Also, added the scenario not able to handle. I guess i have to write another patch for it.

Comment: If you only want to close 'A' rows, then just modify `WHERE a.status <> 'C'` in the outer query to be `WHERE a.status = 'A'`.   Now I am more confused...your updated sample rows show an 'A' record with a NULL end_dt.  That is considered still active, right?  I ran the previous query against the 5 rows you provided...see my updated response for the results.  I feel like I'm not following this correctly.